# Cannot access Google Map Framework in Swift AppDelegate file

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, xcode6

I'm studying Swift and am struggling to figure out how to integrate the Google Map SDK frameworks. I created a new project in Xcode 6, imported the frameworks required as per Google Map SDK instructions for iOS.

However when I import the Google Maps framework using (import )to the AppDelegate.swift file the framework isn't recognised.

Can't find a solution anywhere. Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After you imported Google Maps iOS SDK, you need to have a bridge header defined, then the SDK will be recognized.

To create this bridge header, add an arbitrary Objective-C file(eg: a `.m` file)  to your project. Xcode will prompt to ask you if to configure a bridge header for you.

Click **Yes** to continue.

A file ending with `-Bridging-Header.h` will be added to your project.

Simply add `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` in the bridge header, and you are good to go!

Also, it's safe to delete that temporary Objective-C file now.

Comment: Thank you so much Aaron, that solved my problem. It seems like a bit of a hack creating a .m file purely to get the Bridging Header option, maybe it will be easier in the release version.

Comment: @CathalYea, I agree. I expected the bridge header will be added when an Objecitve-C library is imported to the project. Hope this will be improved in the next seed.

Comment: hi, can you show me how to add the API key into swift please? Thanks. From the google maps sdk: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios Add the following to your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, replacing API_KEY with your API key.
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"API_KEY"];

Comment: @Duc just call `GMSServices.provideAPIKey` with your API key in `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?)`

Comment: Now with Xcode Beta 3 - this no longer seems to work! :(

Answer (score 1):

You can now install SDK via CocoaPods, and you wont need to add the Bridging Header. View this tutorial([Google Maps iOS SDK Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start)) and just add the following code to your AppDelegate's didFinichLaunchingWithOptions function.

```
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("API_KEY")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a temporary Objective-C file to your project. You may give it any name you like.

Select Yes to configure an Objective-C bridging header.

Delete the temporary Objective-C file you just created.

In the projectName-Bridging-Header.h file just created, add this line:

*'#import < GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h >'*

**Edit the AppDelegate.swift file:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIza....") //iOS API key

    return true
}
```

[Follow the link](http://studyswift.blogspot.com/2015/10/using-google-maps-api-in-swift.html) for full sample